# При повторном создании Fragment, Activity не привязывается к нему

Tags: c#, android, android-fragment, xamarin.android

При навигации в приложении создается Activity1, которая добавляет на экран Fragment1.
Вызов Activity1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
StartActivity(intent);
```

При закрытии фрагмента вызывается:

```
Activity.Finish();
```

1) Если в фрагменте вызвать Activity.Finish(), затем заново создать Activity1 через Intent, то fragment1.Activity == null. Почему это происходит?

2) Можно ли это избежать, используя одну активити на все фрагменты, а не создавая для каждого фрагмента свою активити?

**Код Fragment1**

```
    public class Fragment1: Fragment
    {
        static View view;
        public static Fragment1 NewInstance()
        {
            var fragment = new Fragment1();
            return fragment;
        }
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            if (view == null)
            {
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragmentLayout, container, false);
                Button buttonNewActivity = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
                buttonNewActivity.Click += ButtonNewActivity_Click;
                Button buttonCloseActivity = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
                buttonCloseActivity.Click += ButtonCloseActivity_Click;
            }
            else
            {
                if (view.Parent != null)
                    ((ViewGroup)view.Parent).RemoveView(view);
            }
            return view;
        }

        private void ButtonCloseActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Activity != null)
            {
                Activity.Finish();
            }
            else
            {
                // Попадаем сюда при втором вызове activity
            }
        }

        private void ButtonNewActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Activity != null)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(Activity2));
                StartActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                // Попадаем сюда при втором вызове activity
            }
        }
    }
```

**Код Activity1**

```
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        Fragment1 fragment;
        private static String fragment_tag = "fragment_tag";

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (this.Resources.Configuration.Orientation != Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape)
            {
                fragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag<Fragment1>(fragment_tag);
                if (fragment == null)
                {
                    fragment = Fragment1.NewInstance();
                }
                FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Android.Resource.Id.Content, fragment, fragment_tag).Commit();
            }
            else
                Finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Проблема была в этой строчке:

   `static View view;`

   Нельзя объявлять статические переменные, хранящие фрагменты, активности, потому что они будут оставаться в памяти до завершения работы приложения.

## Код Fragment1

```
    public class Fragment1: Fragment
    {
        View view;
        public static Fragment1 NewInstance()
        {
            var fragment = new Fragment1() { };
            return fragment;
        }
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragmentLayout, container, false);
            Button buttonNewActivity = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            buttonNewActivity.Click += ButtonNewActivity_Click;
            Button buttonCloseActivity = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
            buttonCloseActivity.Click += ButtonCloseActivity_Click;
            return view;
        }

        private void ButtonCloseActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                //FragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate();
                Activity.Finish();
        }

        private void ButtonNewActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(Activity2));
                StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

## Код Activity1

```
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (this.Resources.Configuration.Orientation != Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape)
            {
                var fragment = Fragment1.NewInstance();
                FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Add(Android.Resource.Id.Content, fragment).Commit();
            }
            else
                Finish();
        }
    }
```

2. Новые активности имеет смысл создавать, если в них устанавливается новая разметка под фрагменты с помощью: `SetContentView()`. Например, если было две вертикальные колонки с фрагментами, а на новом экране нужны три колонки.